# AJAX Function jQuery to PHP Access Response Variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to send an AJAX function from jQuery to PHP. I can get it to the right page fine, but when I get there, how do I access the data from the AJAX call? It's probably something silly I'm missing.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#assessform_page").on("submit", "#assessform", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var assessrows = {};
        var url = $(this).attr("action");

        $("div[data-test-num]").attr("data-test-num", function(index, value) {
            assessrows[value] = {};
            $(this).children("input[data-tab-row], select[data-tab-row]").attr("data-tab-row", function(i, v) {
                assessrows[value][v] = $(this).val();
            });
            $(this).children("label[data-tab-row]").attr("data-tab-row", function(i, v) {
                assessrows[value][v] = $(this).text();
            });
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: assessrows,
            type: "POST",
            success: function() {
                window.location.href = url;
            },
        });

    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="assessform" action="assessment.php" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="assessform">
    <div data-test-num="1">
        <label data-tab-row="objname">First Value: </label>
        <select autofocus="autofocus" data-tab-row="status">
            <option value="not_started">Not started</option>
            <option value="in progress">In Progress</option>
            <option value="obstacles">Obstacles</option>
            <option value="excluded">Excluded</option>
            <option value="done">Done</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" data-tab-row="numer" value="" />
        <input type="text" data-tab-row="denom" value="" />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button">Submit</button><br />
    <button type="button">Save</button><br />
</form>
```

PHP:

`<?php ?>` (I can't really do anything until I get this variable.)

What variable do I call to get the data from the AJAX, and what function, if any, do I need to call before I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

If your `assessment.php` make a response as follows:

```
  <?php
       echo 'successfully_completed';
  ?>
```

The response data from PHP will be passed as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, // assessment.php
    data: assessrows,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("The response is [" + data + "]"); 
        // "The response is [successfully_completed]"

        // If you want to pass this data to the next page
        window.location.href = "/foo/success.php?data="+data;  
    }
});
```

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have gone clogging up the global namespace. I'm not really gonna do anything else with it, but you're still right. Also, I had it as a variable when I wrote it, but I was testing stuff & it was a string when I copied it into the question. Will change it back.

Comment: The linked question talked about how you return the data on a JavaScript page, but what I'm asking is how to return it on a PHP page.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Do you mean you are asking the way to send data from javascript to PHP?

Comment: No, I'm already sending it. If you notice, the URL goes to a PHP page, not a JavaScript page. I'm asking how I get the data variable once I'm there.

Comment: In your code, You are posting data to the url and jumping to the same url after sccessfully completed. Could you elaborate on that? Why you need this.

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm kind of new to AJAX & thought that was how you do that. I just want to pass variables from jQuery to PHP.

Comment: Can I send variables separately from the "jumping to the next page"? For example, can I send the variables first, then have them be on the page when I get there?

Comment: It's possible, but not easy. Because separated two HTTP requests should be connected on server-side somehow. I guess your easiest way is posting data by only html, not using javascript. In this case you just add `name` attribute to each `input` tags, and submit to `assessment.php`.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like maybe I won't need more than `name` after all. Still annoyed we can't, though. I'll accept your answer, as it did technically answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    data: assessrows,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); //do something with data
        window.location.href = url;
    },
});
```

Comment: Should I do something with data in the success function before it goes to the PHP page? Will that help me access it from there?

Comment: I did not know you wanted to do that, but it looks like @naoki already has it covered.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty new to AJAX, so I don't really know what you can & can't do with it.